# LINQ - List Lowest Prices Only

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this code:

```
var items = (new[] { 
    new {itemTypeId = 1 , cost=100 },
    new {itemTypeId = 2 , cost=200 },
    new {itemTypeId = 1 , cost=50 },
    new {itemTypeId = 3 , cost=150 },
    new {itemTypeId = 1 , cost=75 }
});

var o = items.OrderBy(x => x.cost)
    .ToList()
    .GroupBy(x => x.itemTypeId )
    .Select(g => new { g, count = g.Count() })
    .SelectMany(t => t.g.Select(b => b).Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, t.count), (j, i) => new { j.itemTypeId , j.cost }));

foreach (var i in o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ", i.itemTypeId, i.cost);
}
```

Output:

```
1 | 50  
1 | 75  
1 | 100  
3 | 300  
2 | 200
```

I actually want it to output:

```
1 | 50   
2 | 200
3 | 300
```

The query should only return products of a certain type with the lowest price. So in any returned data there should only be one of each item type and ordered by price.

I thought `Enumerable.Range(1, t.count)` did a similar job as `Row_number over` in TSQL.Personally I can't see what on earth the above code actually achieves unless I've written it complete wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the 300 coming from?  Shouldn't it be 150?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to group by `itemTypeId` and then take the lowest by ordering the group by `cost:`

```
var o = items
    .GroupBy(x => x.itemTypeId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.cost).First())
    .OrderBy(x => x.cost);
```

Comment: In my real world code I have a .SelectMany which pulls in data from other tables. I'm a bit lost as to how to combine this with your solution above. I've edited my question to show. Sorry - I'm pushing my luck!

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb: maybe you want to ask another question. It's difficult to understand it without sample data or how the tables are related. You should also mention the LINQ provider if it's not LINQ-To-Objects.

Comment: Fair enough - will do. Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

Group by the item type, which gives you an `IGrouping<T>`, from that you get a key and an `IEnumerable<T>` of grouped items. You can then project (`Select`) that into an anonymous type, using `Min` on the `IGrouping<T>` that is `x` to get the lowest cost per group:

```
items
    .GroupBy(x => x.itemTypeId)
    .Select(x => new { ItemTypeId = x.Key, Cost = x.Min(z => z.cost) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Cost)
```

Comment: People trying to learn linq, especially aggregation functions, benefit greatly from an explanation.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, I was about to add some explanation when I realized that I may be missing some `OrderBy`. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Technically the ordering will give the desired output, assuming an order of item type (the desired output is ambiguous on the required ordering, because it also is ordered by lowest cost first), but I think the main source of confusion was the grouping, and your answer tackles that.